# Atlas for a Riemann Surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to find atlas for Riemann surface given by:

$ X = \{ (z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | z^2 = w^3 \} $

Also is there are a standard way of computing the charts for such spaces?

Comment: Would this be a Riemann surface at the origin $(0,0)$?

Comment: It should not be. For example the partial and the polynomial are both zero. I pointed this out to my professor. But wanted to double check. Thanks